# gcc - error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

Tags: c, pointers, struct, unions, dereference

I have a rather convoluted set of nested structs/unions as shown:

```
typedef enum {
    expr_BooleanExpr,
    expr_ArithmeticExpr
} expr_type;

typedef union {
    struct BooleanExpr *_bool;
    struct ArithmeticExpr *_arith;
} u_expr;

typedef struct {
    expr_type type;
    u_expr *expr;
} Expression;

typedef struct {
    Expression *lhs;
    char *op;
    Expression *rhs;
} BooleanExpr;

typedef struct {
    Expression *lhs;
    char *op;
    Expression *rhs;
} ArithmeticExpr;
```

gcc is happy for me to create an Expression struct containing a BoolExpression value in its union field as shown:

```
Expression *BooleanExpr_init(Expression *lhs, char *op, Expression *rhs) {

    BooleanExpr *_bool = safe_alloc(sizeof(BooleanExpr));
    _bool->lhs = lhs;
    _bool->op = op;
    _bool->rhs = rhs;

    Expression *the_exp = safe_alloc(sizeof(Expression));
    the_exp->type = expr_BooleanExpr;
    the_exp->expr->_bool = _bool;

    return the_exp;
}
```

although  it gives a warning: **assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]** for the line: `the_exp->expr->_bool = _bool;`

However, when accessing the inner expressions such as `lhs` and `rhs`, with an expression like

```
an_expr->expr->_bool->rhs
```

where `an_expr` is a previously created Expression struct, I get the error specified in the title of this post.

Much of what I've read says that this results from the use of the `->` operator where the `.` operator is required. However this is not appropriate since everything is a pointer, so the implicit dereference of the `->` operator is required.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think add strct in declaration `BooleanExpr *_bool = safe_alloc(` should be `struct BooleanExpr *_bool = safe_alloc(`, try this then you may get different  error.

Comment: I've tried this, and it causes the subsequent statements: `_bool->lhs = lhs; _bool->op = op; _bool->rhs = rhs;` to all give the error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

Comment: Don't use identifiers like `_bool` or `_arith` starting with an underscore for your own stuff, they are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: @AlexJ136 As I said I was aware of it. :) ,  you got an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing `typedef` identifiers and `struct` scope identifiers. This can't work. Do something like

```
typedef struct  BooleanExpr BooleanExpr;
```

before all your `struct` declarations and have these only as

```
struct BooleanExpr { ...
```

without the `typedef`.

In your code you never defined `struct  BooleanExp` but only an anonymous `struct` that you alias to the identifier `BooleanExp`.